# Mysql temp columns doesn't reset

Tags: python, mysql

i have a python function with sql query.

```py
def DownloadLastMsgs(username,conn, cursor):
    cursor.execute("SELECT reciver, sender, encoded_to, msg, send_time, Opened \
    FROM \
     (SELECT reciver, sender, encoded_to, msg, send_time, Opened,  \
                  @msg_rank := IF(@current_sender = sender, @msg_rank + 1, 1) AS msg_rank, \
                  @current_sender := sender  \
       FROM MSG \
       ORDER BY sender, send_time DESC \
     ) ranked \
    WHERE (reciver =  %(u)s OR sender= %(u)s) AND encoded_to = %(u)s  AND msg_rank <= 1", {'u': username}) 
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    print(data)
    return data
```

I can use this function only once and then it breaks.

When I change `msg_rank` to `<=2` i can use it twice. I suposse that the function doesn't reset? somehow?

When I try to use this command in adminer sql command it works fine everytime....

How can i fix it? is there a way to reset this temp columns?

Comment: Use triple quotes for multi-line strings so you don't need all those backslashes.

Comment: That's correct, `@variables` don't reset between queries. That allows you to initialize them in one query and use them in the next. So just do `cursor.execute("SET @msg_rank = 0")` first.

Comment: Or you can join with a subquery: `CROSS JOIN (SELECT @msg_rank := 0, @current_sender = NULL) AS variables`

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8.0 yet? Window functions are a more reliable way of doing what you're doing.